# How to convert list of arrays to single list in python?

Tags: python

I have a list of arrays as follows:

```
list = [
         array([4.1,3.2,5.2]),
         array([4.1,8.5]),
         array([1.2,4.5,7.4])
        ]
```

I want to convert the above list into a single list as below:

```
list = [4.1,3.2,5.2,4.1,8.5,1.2,4.5,7.4]
```

I want to do the above thing in python.

**EDIT:**

The code I used to generate the list is

```
  result = []
  result.append(mfccs_processed)
  result.append(chroma_processed)
  result.append(mel_processed)
```

Now result is showing as follows:

```
[array([-445.43651286,  111.90097184,  -21.00590592,   31.34361885,
      9.39596702,   -4.40772227,    2.3648624 ,   -1.68017743,
     -6.39975114,   -1.12694295,   -9.34500736,   -1.13545822,
     -7.88168904,  -10.9743485 ,   -2.77344424,   -1.23599528,
     -7.39119564,   -2.44394294,   -3.75691633,   -4.80426688,
     -1.94571499,   -3.95747011,   -5.72427054,   -4.81378321,
     -3.70200738,   -5.19167481,   -4.47207894,   -4.2216418 ,
     -4.1305041 ,   -5.10309738,   -3.89591536,   -2.67058964,
     -4.04656319,   -4.78655754,   -2.44667325,   -3.05293339,
     -4.17915009,   -2.90706455,   -2.8132492 ]), array([0.548945  , 0.59981299, 0.58249648, 0.5834056 , 0.62918682,
   0.58651369, 0.51776701, 0.5152288 , 0.56039473, 0.5606346 ,
   0.59585897, 0.56108877]), array([5.36600691e-05, 3.20399714e-04, 1.19905308e-03, 3.57715592e-03,
   5.45226355e-03, 7.65769149e-02, 9.67304585e-01, 1.37048258e+00,
   2.20317190e+00, 1.47716846e+00, 7.10145651e-01, 7.23264577e-02,
   3.20378431e-02, 2.13741716e-01, 3.50276892e-01, 3.25545211e-01,
   8.23071739e-01, 1.10485735e+00, 5.16918943e-01, 8.84181377e-01,
   9.06340752e-01, 3.95779410e-01, 3.13891357e-01, 1.13048804e-01,
   6.61881599e-01, 1.70450985e+00, 1.82170031e+00, 6.18310782e-01,
   4.05325714e-01, 5.89335840e-01, 4.31023403e-01, 9.29283876e-02,
   4.11129880e-02, 1.71606268e-01, 1.41923368e-01, 9.29835332e-02,
   1.45740019e-01, 1.27688893e-01, 2.34819748e-02, 9.72517361e-03,
   3.63473003e-02, 5.93138929e-02, 3.11671706e-02, 1.18442648e-02,
   8.33423898e-03, 1.87190944e-02, 3.29460414e-02, 2.69168857e-02,
   9.29586223e-03, 6.80686607e-03, 9.94785389e-03, 1.27595168e-02,
   8.88170288e-03, 7.44158290e-03, 9.98228524e-03, 1.63925465e-02,
   9.53423946e-03, 1.05554487e-02, 1.54851110e-02, 2.05146191e-02,
   1.30264012e-02, 7.20523041e-03, 1.83835207e-02, 1.00800192e-02,
   9.16292185e-03, 2.75197205e-02, 1.26532376e-02, 5.50722000e-03,
   8.06991937e-03, 4.67484356e-03, 9.11601494e-03, 9.94969137e-03,
   8.82691376e-03, 1.35812921e-02, 3.38891723e-02, 5.48777803e-02,
   5.47833810e-02, 3.91788967e-02, 2.34909778e-02, 1.59119884e-02,
   1.76145638e-02, 2.31054147e-02, 2.95776919e-02, 4.17103322e-02,
   2.07705960e-02, 1.08400124e-02, 6.43834017e-03, 4.46195474e-03,
   4.44256498e-03, 5.25020141e-03, 1.14951221e-02, 1.41466409e-02,
   1.73377342e-02, 1.41098637e-02, 7.04262356e-03, 3.99505900e-03,
   2.48446049e-03, 1.61739298e-03, 9.00339387e-04, 3.25213392e-04,
   2.93450309e-04, 3.10071719e-04, 2.85876075e-04, 1.78957305e-04,
   1.38316595e-04, 1.07859368e-04, 1.15453318e-04, 8.50033585e-05,
   7.25839567e-05, 3.80280533e-05, 3.57639077e-05, 2.47069514e-05,
   1.57980270e-05, 1.50489378e-05, 1.12732923e-05, 1.08223414e-05,
   1.21111000e-05, 1.57062296e-05, 1.11814270e-05, 9.70704523e-06,
   8.27147728e-06, 6.56079447e-06, 5.53983257e-06, 5.31472585e-06,
   2.77939077e-06, 1.77413323e-06, 1.03589758e-06, 6.50496670e-08])]
```

Since I already converted my whole dataset using this code above. Now I want to convert the above generated lists into a single list as I explained above. I hope this clarifies the problem. Could you help me out.

Comment: What type of array are you using in your example? is it numpy?

Comment: Flattening a list is well documented.  Please show the code you've written and explain where you're stuck.

Comment: @Prune Please look the problem now I have edited it.

Comment: where is the you tried toflatten the list

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  The "example" you posted does not run, and does not appear to relate to the data you provided.

Comment: @unpredictable I believe you need `np.concatenate` or `np.hstack`. See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html.

Comment: Use [`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) to join all array into one and then use [`tolist`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) to convert that array into list. - `np.concatenate(lst).tolist()`

Answer (score 2):

Try using `list.extend` instead of `append`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using numpy you can use `list.flatten`. https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html

If you have a list of numpy arrays you can use `np.hstack`. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html

Also see [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists) for general Python.

Answer (score 0):

**Using List Comprehensions**

```
items = [item for array in array.tolist() for item in array]
```

**Using Numpy Module**

```
np.concatenate(list).ravel().tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use python keyword (`list`) as a variable name. They are used to define the syntax and structure of the Python language. In Python, keywords are case sensitive.

Use `np.concatenate` to join sequences of an array and `tolist()` to convert numpy array to list.

```
listt = [
         np.array([4.1,3.2,5.2]),
         np.array([4.1,8.5]),
         np.array([1.2,4.5,7.4])
        ]

np.concatenate(listt).tolist()
```